# How can I get mercurial to run meld for merging on Windows+Cygwin?

Tags: configuration, mercurial, installation, cygwin, meld

On Linux, my mercurial (hg) installation runs meld for resolving merging... but this does not happen on Windows with Cygwin. I've noticed Cygwin doesn't even have a meld package, so I tried to get/build merge myself - and got into trouble. The package on meldmerge.org requires pygtk and intltool-merge, which Cygwin doesn't have. If I had meld working I would probably be able to figure out how to use `.hgrc` to run it like it's supposed to - or maybe not?

So, can someone point me to (or spell out) some clear instructions regarding prerequisites and actions necessary to get meld+mercurial working?

**Notes:**

- I use Windows 7 64bit.
- I use 32-bit Cygwin; if it's easier with 64-bit I'm willing to switch.

Comment: http://poquitopicante.blogspot.ru/2012/03/building-meld-for-cygwin.html

Comment: @LazyBadger: `make install` fails, like I wrote in my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forget about Cygwin (better - forever)
2. Install toolset with native components: Mercurial|TortoiseHG + [Windows Meld](http://sourceforge.net/projects/meld-installer/)
3. At least for TortoiseHG after p.2 Meld appear in list of possible differs|mergers (`$TortoiseHg\hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc` have Meld's section)
4. Enable using Meld in Global or repository-only settings

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was asking about Cygwin.

Comment: In my experience windows meld doesn't work very well, unfortunately. iirc files get trashed pretty quickly, maybe me newline related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Packages of `meld` for both 32-bit and 64-bit Cygwin is available at [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/).

Comment: But won't this require an X server?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it will integrate much better with a cygwin hg.